# Hosting Spring Boot / MongoDB Application in Cloud

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, cloud

I will host my Spring Boot/ MongoDB application, developed with Java-8 in the cloud (in Europe and if possible in Germany - a demand of the customer).
I did a research and I really found a lot of possibilities. 
The one that I think fits best are

```
Microsoft Azure and
AWS
```

honestly I dont know how to start. Does anyone know if there is a good tutorial to start - e.g. for installing MongoDB, than for uploading my **jar** file. 
And than I would start my application with **java -jar myApp.jar**.
Is there a good how to do link?

Answer (score 0):

If you're open to using Kubernetes then you could look at the example of https://github.com/nhatthai/spring-mongodb-minikube or  https://github.com/elizabetht/kubernetes-mongo-docker-spring-boot You could use Azure's AKS as I'm guessing you wouldn't want to spend much time on cluster management. (AWS's EKS offering is still in preview mode at the moment.) If you did go this route you could test on a local cluster with minikube. It sounds like you're looking for a cloud provider but you might instead want to use Kubernetes as a cloud-agnostic orchestrator for your application. (On this you might want to look at [Is Kubernetes + Docker + AWS = Azure + Service Fabric?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48520301/is-kubernetes-docker-aws-azure-service-fabric) ) This is just a suggestion - you could instead choose to go for something provider-specific e.g. using Azure's CosmosDB https://github.com/Azure-Samples/azure-cosmos-db-mongodb-spring